# Extract a random value from a JSON response using Groovy in Jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to set two variables `Latitude`, `Longitude` as a random Lat/Long value found in the JSON response. The JSON response contains a `Locations` array containing a list of Lat/Long values. Every time this script is ran, I want my variable to be set to random lat/long values from the Locations array. The Groovy script is a JSR223 PostProcessor with the nested within the POST HTTP request. Below I will post an example response and the Groovy code to achieve this.

```
{
  "Result": {
    "Locations": [
      {
        "Latitude": 38.657,
        "Longitude": -120.377997
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.6566,
        "Longitude": -120.3791
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.658399,
        "Longitude": -120.3804
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.655499,
        "Longitude": -120.38496
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.654,
        "Longitude": -120.3819
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.6537,
        "Longitude": -120.3897
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.6544,
        "Longitude": -120.382604
      },
      {
        "Latitude": 38.655602,
        "Longitude": -122.386402
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The Groovy Script I'm using is:

```
import groovy.json.*

//Parse JSON
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
def LocationsList = JsonOutput.toJson(response.Result.Locations)

//Get the size of Locations Array and Generate Random Number based on array size
Random random = new Random()
int max = LocationsList.size()
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max)

//Get Latitude
def GetLatitude (number) {
    return LocationsList[number].Latitude
}
def Latitude = GetLatitude(randomNumber)

//Get Longitude
def GetLongitude (number) {
    return LocationsList[number].Longitude
}
def Longitude = GetLongitude(randomNumber)

//Set the env vars
vars.put("Latitude", Latitude)
vars.put("Longitude", Longitude)
```

The response I'm getting is long so I will post the important part.

```
     Problem in JSR223 script, CurrentGPS
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: LocationsList for class: Script18
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[java.scripting:?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issue in your script:

- `LocationsList` is incorrectly getting value.
- `LocationsList` is being accessed in both the methods which is not scope. You could have used `Closure` instead.

Here is the fixed script:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
def locations = json.Result.Locations
def randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(locations.size())
def latitude = locations[randomNumber].Latitude
def longitude = locations[randomNumber].Longitude
```

You can quickly try the online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/T3GCbf)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Rao! This worked like a charm. The only thing I had to do was add toString() to the latitude/longitude variables so it looked like this:
def latitude = locations[randomNumber].Latitude.toString()
def longitude = locations[randomNumber].Longitude.toString()

Answer (score 3):

In case when JSON Path expression returns multiple matches you can get a random one without any scripting using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). The component is available since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) and given you provide `0` as "Match No" it will return random value from whatever your JSON Path Expression matches. The configuration would be something like:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor Configuration]

Text representation:

- Names of created variables: `Latitude;Longitude`
- JSON Path Expressions: `$..Latitude;$..Longitude`
- Match No: `0`
- Default Values: `NA;NA`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T! I didn’t know you could use the JSON extractor to assign random values to more than 1 variable. This is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with JSON Extractor and `$..Latitude;$..Longitude` will not work if you want to have matching longitude and latitude from a random array item - that pattern gives you a random latitude and a random longitude.

If you want to have both from the same random pair and prefer to use JSON Extractor, then you have to use 3 instances:

1. first, extract the random pair using `$.Result.Locations.*` pattern on the main sample:
   [extract random pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrxqa.png)
2. then extract the latitude using the above variable as the source and pattern `$.Latitude`:
   [extract latitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWtM1.png)
3. do the same for Longitude.